# How can execute launchctl load start in a Macosx App using swift?

Tags: swift, macos, applescript, launchd

I want to develop an MacOS app to manage some of my own processes. 
I thought I should use launchd, but I found that when I use launchd to start the process, it always fails. The error is as follows:

```
0:86: execution error: 2020-03-11 17:15:02.213472+0800 launchctl[9835:373247] [All] launchctl start: launchctl start com.example.myprocess (3)
```

I have closed the sandbox.
I used Apple Script to apply for root permissions. Like:

```
do shell script \"launchctl start com.example.myprocess\" with administrator privileges
```

How should i deal with this, thanks.

Here is my swift code:

```
Button(action: {
//    let bundle = Bundle.main
//    let cmd = bundle.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "sh")!
//    let cmd = "launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.example.myprocess.plist"
    let cmd  = "launchctl start com.example.myprocess"
    let process = Process()
    process.launchPath = "/usr/bin/osascript"
    let arg = String.init(format: "do shell script \"%@\" with administrator privileges with prompt \"XXXXX\"", cmd)
    print(arg)
    process.arguments = ["-e", arg]
    process.launch()
    process.waitUntilExit()
    print("status: ", process.terminationStatus)
}) {
    Text("Start")
}.disabled(isRunning).padding(.trailing)
```

Here is my plist code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.example.myprocess</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/Users/tang/bin/myprocess</string>
            <string>start</string>
        </array>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/Users/tang/myprocess.log</string>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/Users/tang/myprocess.log</string>
        <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
        <string>/Users/tang/</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: It's very hard to diagnose what's wrong with a process we can't see running under a `plist` file we can't see either.

Comment: Could you share your swift code, please? At least the pertinent parts of the method where this error arises.

Comment: Here is my plist and swift code. Please help me check again.

Comment: Observation: You are making your life extremely difficult through task-switching. You're using `Process` to run a unix script that runs an AppleScript that runs a unix script to load a plist. each step in that chain is going to need separate authorization, for no particularly good reason. Just run the `launchctl` command directly, without the indirection. Your application will need to have root privileges if you want to run this as root, I think.

Comment: I solved this problem using qt. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app I developed using QT can easily call shell scripts and execute launchd commands.
This is my demo app source code: https://github.com/yiwenlong/launchduidemo